# Why is my ASP.net MVC Site Not Serving Pages on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net-mvc

Why is my ASP.net MVC site not serving pages on Windows Server 2008? The website is running under an application pool that has the .net framework 4.0 in integrated mode. It serves .htm files with no problem. When I try to view any of the MVC pages I get a page saying "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage." There are no errors in the event log. How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. This was a pain to track down. The server hosts 2 websites. The HTTPS bindings were not associated with the IP address for the website. Instead, the IP binding was set to "All unassigned".

The solution was to associate the HTTPS binding with the website's IP address.